# How to send a form with multiple select lists by clicking enter

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have found some threads where this is realized with the JS onkeypress function but all forms have input fields and the JS function is linked to them. So I have no clue how to do it with a form where I have no input field but multiple select lists. It works perfectly with the submit button but in addition I want it to happen by pressing enter. So I just want to link the enter key with my submit button - if possible without jQuery

My code is something like:

```
    <button form='form1' type='submit' name='setfilter'>filter</button>

    <form id='form1' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
    <select name='filter_1[]' multiple size='5'><option selected>%</option></select>
    <select name='filter_2[]' multiple size='5'><option selected>%</option></select>
    <select name='filter_3[]' multiple size='5'><option selected>%</option></select>
    </form>
```

Then on the server side

```
    if (isset($_POST['filter_1'])).....
    echo ...
```

Comment: What's the exact problem here? Are you sure this problem is in any way related to PHP? If yes, can you share all code in question? For example, the given code does not contain a single line of JS

Comment: It is also possible without JavaScript if you include the submit button inside the form. This is actually what [W3C](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_forms_-_the_basics?&sa=U&ei=uPgMVISQGoXJPPytgeAF&ved=0CDEQ9QEwBw&usg=AFQjCNHpg4hgsyMcM6BUeY85QIpZHIjqKQ) states its normal to do when you work with forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plain JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class_of_select")
    .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("id_of_button_tosubmit").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution but nothing changed :(

Comment: Have you checked the console? Is there no errors?

Comment: It says: 
TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function

Comment: I added document in frot of .addEventListener and now it works.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Notice, that form must be in focus (click on select fields). Here you go:

```js
var form = document.getElementById("form1");
form.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<button form='form1' type='submit' name='setfilter'>filter</button>
<form id='form1' action='' method='post'>
    <select name='filter_1[]' multiple size='5'>
        <option selected>%</option>
    </select>
    <select name='filter_2[]' multiple size='5'>
        <option selected>%</option>
    </select>
    <select name='filter_3[]' multiple size='5'>
        <option selected>%</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. For example, what do you mean by "form must be in focus"?